# jQuery s.toFixed error when using slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm trying to create a slider to handle the scrubbing of a html5 video player, it worked fine using a HTML5 range element but now i need to extend to functionality of the slider, which led me to using jQueryUI's slider.

When attempting to move the slider, the following error pops up in console:

```
jquery-ui.min.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: s.toFixed is not a function
at t.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._trimAlignValue (https://pops-cdn.s3.amazonaws.com/js/jquery-ui.min.js:12:6540)
at t.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._trimAlignValue (https://pops-cdn.s3.amazonaws.com/js/jquery-ui.min.js:6:4499)
at t.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._normValueFromMouse (https://pops-cdn.s3.amazonaws.com/js/jquery-ui.min.js:12:3356)
at t.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._normValueFromMouse (https://pops-cdn.s3.amazonaws.com/js/jquery-ui.min.js:6:4499)
at t.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._mouseDrag (https://pops-cdn.s3.amazonaws.com/js/jquery-ui.min.js:12:2516)
at t.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._mouseDrag (https://pops-cdn.s3.amazonaws.com/js/jquery-ui.min.js:6:4499)
at t.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._mouseMove (https://pops-cdn.s3.amazonaws.com/js/jquery-ui.min.js:9:24056)
at t.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._mouseMove (https://pops-cdn.s3.amazonaws.com/js/jquery-ui.min.js:6:4499)
at HTMLDocument.n._mouseCapture._mouseDistanceMet._mouseDelayMet._mouseMoveDelegate (https://pops-cdn.s3.amazonaws.com/js/jquery-ui.min.js:9:23414)
at HTMLDocument.dispatch (https://pops-cdn.s3.amazonaws.com/js/jquery.min.js:3:10316)
```

The code I am using is as follows, please note, this is written under the backbone.js framework and using videojs.

```
var self    = this,
player      = window.player;
$('#slider').slider({
  animate: false,
  min: 0,
  max: player.duration(),
  value: 0,
  step: 1,
  slide: function(event, ui)
  {
    if (ui.value % 5 == 0)
    {
      player.currentTime(ui.value,true);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Just a guess, but try forcing the `max` value to a float: `max: parseFloat(player.duration()),`

Comment: What is the result of `player.duration()`?